# smb prompting me for root password?

Tags: windows, networking, linux-networking

I issued the command:

```
   sudo smbclient -L //serverXYZ
```

to list the shares on a remote Windows server on the network and Ubuntu system asked me first for my password (I am a sudoer), then it asked me for the root password, which I do not know.

What is the story here? Why do I need to know the root password to list remote shares?

Answer (score 2):

SMBClient uses your user account name for the remote server when you don't provide any username for it. When you are running the command via `sudo`, your username is `root` and so it is logging into remote server as `root`.

You need to specify the username to use at the remote server with the `-U <username>` parameter.